# Mysql select by best match with like

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `accounts` 
WHERE AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) = CONCAT_WS('@',:mailbox,:host)
OR AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) LIKE CONCAT('%',:host)
```

I have 2 records in that table:

```
id     email
1      test@test.com
2      other@test.com
```

When I'm running this query like this:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `accounts` 
WHERE AES_DECRYPT(`email`, '123') = CONCAT_WS('@','test','test.com') 
OR AES_DECRYPT(`email`, '123') LIKE CONCAT('%','test.com')
```

I get this as a result:

```
id     email
2      other@test.com
1      test@test.com
```

**Question:**
What I want is this: I want to have the best match as the first result, without using fulltext search.
Is this possible, if so, how can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by best match?

Comment: When I search for test@test.com, I want to have test@test.com as the first result. test@test.com has a better match than other@test.com. I want the result with the most matching characters to end up on top.

Comment: Sorry to say, this looks like a strange rule to me. So gmail@gmail.com is better than someone@gmail.com? And gmail@yahoo.com is as good as someone@gmail.com when looking for gmail? And someone@gmail.com is as good as someone@dogmail.com? I think you should refine your rules and then come back here.

Comment: try to order by Desc to your result set

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, If you look at my query, I'm searching for test@test.com, so obviously test@test.com has a better match than other@test.com

Comment: @KhurramAli Order by what field?

Comment: @FIA2008: Yes, sorry for this. I didn't read your request properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily order the results by the number of matches:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `accounts`
WHERE AES_DECRYPT(`email`, '123') = CONCAT_WS('@', 'test', 'test.com') OR 
      AES_DECRYPT(`email`, '123') LIKE CONCAT('%','test.com')
ORDER BY ( (AES_DECRYPT(`email`, '123') = CONCAT_WS('@', 'test', 'test.com')) +
           (AES_DECRYPT(`email`, '123') LIKE CONCAT('%','test.com'))
         );
```

This will work for your example.

Answer (score 0):

To get records in a specific order, use an ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `accounts` 
WHERE AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) = CONCAT_WS('@',:mailbox,:host)
OR AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) LIKE CONCAT('%',:host)
order by AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) = CONCAT_WS('@',:mailbox,:host) desc;
```

Here we are using a MySQL special. A boolean expression that evaluates to TRUE results in 1. A boolean expression that evaluates to FALSE results in 0. In another DBMS you could write this instead:

```
order by 
 case when AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) = CONCAT_WS('@',:mailbox,:host)
      then 1 else 0 end desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should suit you:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `accounts` 
    WHERE AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) = CONCAT_WS('@',:mailbox,:host)
    OR AES_DECRYPT(`email`, :salt) LIKE CONCAT('%',:host)
    ORDER BY LENGTH(`email`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`email`, :host, '')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`email`, :mailbox, '')) DESC
```