# best match result query in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i have table named books and want to display "related books" in books view.

```
books table
`book_id`
`isbn`
`book_name`
`author_name`
`Date`
`number`
`language`
`Translator`
`abstract`
`picture`
`created_at`
```

controller code

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model=$this->findModel($id);
    $dataProvider=$this->related($model);
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
protected function related($model)
{
    $query = Books::find();
    $query->select('book_id,picture, book_name,author_name,(( author_name LIKE \'%'.$model->author_name.'%\')+( book_name LIKE \'%'.$model->book_name.'%\')) as total')
    ->orFilterwhere(['or like','author_name' , explode(' ',$model->author_name)])
    ->orFilterwhere(['or like','book_name' , explode(' ',$model->book_name)])
    ->orderBy('total')
    ->limit(25);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

problom :
book_name `LIKE \'%'.$model->book_name.'%\'` did not accept array. 
something like `LIKE \'%'.explode(' ',$model->book_name).'%\'`
its must be an array to work correctly.
how can i use array in select condition .
or show me some other way to get best match result on top.
tnx

Comment: Like the error says, you have an `Array` and you are apparently trying to use it as a `String`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: i know that . i want to know how can i use array, instead. it must be like "orFilterwhere" condition to work

Comment: Annnnnnd i guess we are suppose to... well guess it ? Thats not  what your question is about, that's not in the title, you say that litterally nowhere in your question, how am i suppose to know that you want to use an array, because right now what i understand is "I've got this error but can't find out why help plz". Learn how to ask a proper question before complaining, peoples won't try to guess what you want for hours, jeez.

Comment: @SaLaR,your have array of names ?? and you want to find name from that array ??

Comment: sorry. i was not complaining.just trying to clear subject.

Comment: @Peerbits - Backend Team,yes, not just finding, i have a book , and i want to find other books like it, and display best match first. for search i use an array.actully i Convert string book_name to array book_name.for example "css design" --> (css,design). result wiil be for "css" or "design" or both

Answer (score 0):

First If you want Total no need to write where condition in select

```
$query->select('book_id,picture, book_name,author_name,(book_name+author_name) as total');
```

`$model->author_name` And `$model->book_name` is Array So you can do as below.

```
protected function related($model)
{
    $query = Books::find();
    $query->select('book_id,picture, book_name,author_name,(book_name+author_name) as total');

     $author_names=  explode(' ',$model->author_name);
     foreach($author_names as $author_name)
     {
      $query->orFilterwhere(['like','author_name' , $author_name]);
     }

     $book_names=explode(' ',$model->book_name);
     foreach($book_names as $book_name)
     {
      $query->orFilterwhere(['like','book_name' , $book_name]);
     }
    ->orderBy('total')
    ->limit(25);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: tnx, about where conditions, you'r righ. i need to Set 'total' with number for example the Book name is "css design" and another book name is "css" total wil be "1" and if another bokk name is "web design with css" total wil be "2" .and thats how can i get best match on top.such as this (but with array) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28694781/9668341)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [MySQL match() against()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) feature (or substitute if you're using different DB).

```
$query = Books::find();
$query->select([
    'book_id,picture', 'book_name', 'author_name',
    new Expression('MATCH (author_name) AGAINST (:author_name) + MATCH (book_name) AGAINST (:book_name) AS total', [
        'author_name' => $this->author_name,
        'book_name' => $this->book_name,
    ]),
]);

if (!empty($this->author_name)) {
    $query->andWhere(new Expression('MATCH (author_name) AGAINST (:author_name)', [
        'author_name' => $this->author_name,
    ]));
}
if (!empty($this->book_name)) {
    $query->andWhere(new Expression('MATCH (book_name) AGAINST (:book_name)', [
        'book_name' => $this->book_name,
    ]));
}
$query->orderBy('total DESC')
    ->limit(25);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```